# try-catch when adding value to ArrayList is out of bound using loop Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

I'd like to add all values as 0.0 to an ArrayList which the size is set to be MAX=5. I am using a for loop to add the values. I would like to catch a out of bounds exception when the list is exceeding MAX size. A message would output the reason that the list size should be 5. Then it would print out the list values which would be 5 "0.0". 
I would test it by changing the MAX value to 8:

```
try {   
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) 
myList.add(0.0);
```

I've tried putting the try{} inside the loop and add() after the while loop. The output would either be not catching the exception or doesn't return anything. The code I have below doesn't return anything. 
I must be asking the wrong questions because I can't seem to find the answer. Or that I am getting the logic completely wrong...I'd appreciate any guidance!

```
//This code doesn't return anything
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class Values {
private static final int MAX = 5;
private ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(MAX); 

public Values()  {

try {   
for (int i=0; i< MAX; i++) {
    myList.add(0.0);
while ( i <0 || i > MAX) {}}    
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
System.out.println("ArrayList size allowed at" + MAX);}

for (Double myList: myList) 
System.out.println(myList);
}
```

Comment: i cannot be resolved to a variable this means you never declared i

Comment: add some curly braces behind your for loop. otherwise its only "active" for the very next line. once you enclose the while loop inside the curly braces your error is gone

Comment: Although you declared your list with `MAX` length, and if you are adding more, it silently increases it's length internally and adjust accordingly. 

Your best bet is to check against `MAX` and throw your own exception or any existing exception.

Comment: The for loop is finished after the line 'mylist.add(0.0);'. So the variable 'i' is not known in the 'while' loop. Try to format your code correctly, then you see things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st:** 
You are getting error because you have to declare `i` outside the for loop because the scope of `i` was within the `for` loop.

**2nd:**

By `ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(MAX);`  you are not fixing size of `List`. It's only setting it's initial capacity.

You need to something like below(in short):

```
int MAX = 5;

        ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(5);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)// to throw IndexOutOfBoundsException
            {
                if(myList.size()>MAX)
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("My message");
                myList.add(0.0);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+e.getMessage());

        }
```

**N.B:** Usage of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is not required here. Showed just for your question.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications! I understand what I was doing wrong. BTW I changed this code to if(myList.size() >=MAX and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @CocoBeans happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `i` variable declared in the `for` statement has a scope limited to the `for`.
So you will never be able to use it in the `while` statement.

> A message would output the reason that the list size should be 5.

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will not help you here as it will never be risen.
You don't access to an index out of range of the List.
You only add elements in and `List.add()` and `ArrayList.add()`doesn't specify any exception in their javadoc.

Now, if you did `list.get(4)` on a list with a size of 4, the exception would be risen as :

> **E java.util.ArrayList.get(int index)**
>
> . . .
>
> **Throws**:
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index >= size())

To ensure you don't exceed a specific number of element in the List, you have to explicitly check it.

In your actual code, you could specify a single entry point to add element in the List and do the check there :

```
for (int i=0; i< MAX; i++) {
    addInList(0.0));
}

public void addInList(Double value){
  if (doubles.size() > MAX){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("ArrayList size allowed at" + MAX);}

    for (Double myList: myList) 
     System.out.println(myList);
   }
  }
  doubles.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` value that you're passing as ArrayList constructor argument is not doing what you're expecting it to do. It is an **initial** capacity. This means that when you first initialize your ArrayList you want it to be able to store **at least** amount of values passed as the constructor 's argument.

To achieve what you're asking I would suggest creating your own "YourException" (name it as you like it) with key words `extends Exception` to make it act like other exceptions. Then you should make some checks when adding each of new values to your ArrayList if its size is being exceeded when trying to add next value to ArrayList. If it occurs you then `throw new YourException()`.

Another possibility is to `throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of throwing YourException, but I don't think it's a good idea - it may be a bit confusing according to fact that ArrayList do not have bounds.